# How to give one package precedence over the other in Atom editor?

Tags: atom-editor

I've been trying to change my color on comment from gray or light-gray (which is the default I think) to my own custom settings like dark-green in Atom Editor. So I created a package on which I want to alter the color setting. However, when I changed the color to light-green in `base.less` like this:

```
.comment {
  color: @dark-green;
}

.punctuation {
  &.definition {
    &.comment {
      color: @dark-green;
    }
}
```

, the result is still not changed at all. I defined the `@dark-green` in `colors.less`.

I'm not sure which of the above two is the correct place to change the color of comment. But those are the result returned by `find` command with `comment` as a keyword, so I changed both.

So I think this is because there are some packages such as `language-html` or `language-python`, on which the comment color remains to be gray, which is I think the default. Is this right? If that's the case, how can I make one package take precedence over the other in order to reflect my own package's color syntax?

I have all packages in `~/.atom/packages/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stylesheets in Atom follow the same specificity rules as CSS in the browser (since Atom is built on top of Chromium). So you just have to make sure that the rule in your package is more specific than the rule in the Theme you're using. (You can find the UI and Syntax themes in Settings under the Themes tab.)

Things to keep in mind when working on stylesheets in a package:

1. The package must be in a place where it can be loaded: either `~/.atom/packages` or `~/.atom/dev/packages`
2. When you make a change you might have to restart Atom if you're not running Atom in Developer Mode
3. If you're running in Developer Mode, it should live reload any stylesheet changes. If it doesn't you can execute `Window: Reload` in the Command Palette

Answer (score 0):

You have likely diagnosed the problem correctly. However, I don't believe there is currently a way to specify the order in which packages are loaded. So, if `language-html` and `language-python` are loaded after your package, then their settings will take precedence.

Have you considered adding your styling to your editor's stylesheet? This is loaded after all packages are loaded and will take precedence. I would argue this is a better approach because it doesn't require you to create a full-blown package just to modify some editor styling. To do this, navigate to *Atom* -> *Open your stylesheet* and add your styles.